# Use getFullName(),equals() function to connect database value and node

Tags: anylogic

I made a function like "getFullName" to connect the string value of database and real node in my main agent.
And then I tried to adapt the node name as a location of source block to move the transporter to node with using dynamic value. # like getFullName(database.columnName)
[node feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZVhI.png) # there's network with nodes and paths.
And I made a collection of node names as Nodename.
[Nodename](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1B6X.png)

I want to know how to adapt the node name in database to real node in main agent.
And should I write the argument in the function. If it is right, what I have to write in there?

Now

```
for (Node n : Nodename) {
   if (getFullName().equals("root" + str_Nodename) == True)
   
   return n;
}
return null;
```

Comment: this video might help you... does the same thing you want to do, but in a bit of a different way:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCieA64CXsU